# Indy http server session doesn't work well

Tags: delphi, indy, httpserver, indy10

How can create session used with in idhttpserver ?

I tryed alot of ways to do but I can't able to reach session object in ARequestInfo.Session or AResponseInfo.Session these are both of them always nil. please help

```
procedure TFolsecPermissionManager.IdHTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Command: TCommand;
  Session: TIdHTTPSession;
begin
  Session := IdHTTPServer.CreateSession(AContext, AResponseInfo, ARequestInfo);
  IdHTTPServer.SessionList.Add(Session);


  Command:= TCommand.Create;
  Command.Start(AContext, ARequestInfo, AResponseInfo);
end;
```

Comment: On a side note, you are leaking your `TCommand` object, as you are not freeing it when you are done using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `TIdHTTPServer.SessionState` is set to `True`.  Optionally, you can also set `TIdHTTPServer.AutoStartSession` to `True` as well.  They are both `False` by default.

If both are `True`, you do not need to call `CreateSession()` manually, as it called automatically for every incoming request that does not carry a cookie for an existing session.

If `SessionState=True` and `AutoStartSession=False`, you do need to call `CreateSession()` manually when desired.

However, no matter what, do not call `SessionList.Add()` manually, as `CreateSession()` calls that internally for you.  You don't want the `SessionList` holding multiple references to the same `TIdHTTPSession` object.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a maximum number of automatically created sessions?  I want some protection against balooning memory requirements in case of a DoS.

Comment: @KurtFitzner not at this time, no. You will have to set `AutoStartSession=False` and then call `CreateSession()` manually whenever you feel its safe to do so.